# Using Cocos2d, to detect if a Sprite is tapped on, we need to do all the calculations?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

For example, if we have 10 rectangle sprites, and we generate them using random width, height, position, and z-index. And now the method

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

is called. How do we know which sprite is tapped on? I know some technique checks whether the tapped point is within the bound of the sprite's rectangle, but in the case described above, what if rect A is on top of rect B at the TOP LEFT corner, and when the TOP LEFT corner of rect B is tapped on, it could be rect A that is tapped on -- the tapping point is actually inside of both rects.

Do we have to do it manually, and even consider the z-index...? (possibly looping through all sprites from the highest z-index to the lowest).

What if the sprite is a triangle, and rotating?  There isn't a built-in way in Cocos2d that handles that?

(that's because I went through Core Graphics sample code a few days ago... seems like in that case, there will be two tap events, one for the main view, and one for the sub-view, and we can check what view it is that the user tapped on, without doing any calculation)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be a subclass of CCSprite that declares itself a delegate for CCStandardTouchDelegate or CCTargetedTouchDelegate. Then perform the appropriate operations on the sprite in those delegate methods.

Comment: Ok, it looks like we can use `CCTargetedTouchDelegate`, but we still have to implement the code ourselves to determine if it is being tapped on in our `ccTouchBegan` code.  And it is more complicated if it is a rectangle or triangle rotated. Or if it is playing cards overlapping each other -- we need to determine if the tap is on the top card or bottom card ourselves.  I think in Core Graphics, it is automatic but I will verify later on and maybe that's why Core Graphics is slower.

Comment: The delegate methods of CCTargetedTouchDelegate will be called on the CCSprite that has the highest z-value. In the CCTouchBegan method, you can claim the touch by responding YES or have it passed to the next highest layer (or sprite) underneath it by responding NO.